# pip install psd-tools3 => FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: pip, pypi, python-packaging

I was trying to install Ursina but I was having trouble getting all the required packages I needed to run my code properly. Come to find out, there's a package that refuses to install called 'psd-tools3' that won't install, no matter what I do.

I've been using cmd commands like 'pip install psd-tools3' and 'pip3 install psd-tools3' but no other commands work (i.e. 'sudo pip install psd-tools3' doesn't work because my PC doesn't know what 'sudo' means and doesn't run). I've tried installing required packages for this package, but nothing works. It just keeps giving me this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DTnO.jpg)

I would really appreciate the help with this problem. All I can really assume is that the Python file '_version' hasn't been created and that's what's throwing the whole program off. If there is a way to add this manually and then install it, I would appreciate steps to do that as well.

I was running this on a Lenovo Thinkpad (Windows 10) on Python 3.10 (I also have Python 3.8.3 but that was installed with the 3.10) and I made sure all packages and pip are up-to-date. Still having this problem and I don't know why.

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy/paste the text in the question.

Comment: Do not use `pip` or `pip3`, instead use `pythonX.Y -m pip`: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: You can not use `sudo` because `sudo` is a Linux thing, and you seem to be on Windows. It is bad advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the issue is on the side of the maintainers of `psd-tools3`.

For example, looking at the content of [the latest source distribution on PyPI](https://inspector.pypi.io/project/psd-tools3/1.9.2/packages/10/e4/e7cd30c5b7ef26ebd99fcc52fd59a66a909e08884482346240a799653f24/psd-tools3-1.9.2.tar.gz/), we can see that it does not contain any `_version.py` file.

This needs to be solved by the [project's maintainers](https://inspector.pypi.io/project/psd-tools3/1.9.2/packages/10/e4/e7cd30c5b7ef26ebd99fcc52fd59a66a909e08884482346240a799653f24/psd-tools3-1.9.2.tar.gz/), but they do not have a ticket tracker. On the other hand there seems to be an "Author" email address on the [project's PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/psd-tools3/) as well as in [the project's `setup.py` script](https://inspector.pypi.io/project/psd-tools3/1.9.2/packages/10/e4/e7cd30c5b7ef26ebd99fcc52fd59a66a909e08884482346240a799653f24/psd-tools3-1.9.2.tar.gz/psd-tools3-1.9.2/setup.py).

A solution might be to clone the [project's source code repository](https://github.com/sfneal/psd-tools3) (with git), and try to install from the local clone.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply try

> pip install psd-tools3==1.9.0

Or

> pip install psd-tools3==1.8.2

This should work on your pc as well. I was having same issue, and then I tried this It worked for me